# Hide mouse arrow on 2D paint mode

Tags: customization, texture-painting

When I'm painting in the Texture Paint mode, I can see both the **blender pointer** (showing the size of the selected tool) and also the **system mouse pointer** (which is an arrow), as shown in the attached screenshot. For me, this is very confusing.

Is there any way to hide that arrow on this mode?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the brush circle, but you can't get rid of the system cursor. Turn off 'Show Brush' in the Options tab.[image: show brush]

Comment: Yes, I knew that. But the brush circle gives me information about the size of the brush. This one is what I would like to maintain. It seems that what I want is imposible (without patching the code of blender). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Maybe you can suggest it on rightclickselect.com and support it with screen grabs. Might not be hard for someone that knows their way around blender.

Comment: Good one, I didn't know rightclickselect.com. Set it on my TODO list. Thanks!

Comment: I tried an app on the mac here at work, and was able to hide the system cursor via a shortcut. I tried painting, and then suddenly realized the problem - I could then not see the system cursor to hover and press on the interface. Certain buttons highlighted, but it was work. You might see if there is already an OS specific solution here instead of changing blender in the meantime, but if you do get something changed the cursor should reappear over UI.